# Oozie hive workflow cannot start with java.lang.StackOverflowError in hue(HA mode)

Tags: workflow, stack-overflow, oozie, high-availability, hue

I'm going to use oozie(4.1.0-cdh5.4.1) in hue(3.7.0), but after I create a hive workflow just to run "select * from table", the error occured as below:

```
2016-04-27 22:59:55,408 ERROR ActionStartXCommand:517 - SERVER[ISHDWS006] USER[hdfs] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[My_Workflow] JOB[0000001-160427224800779-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000001-160427224800779-oozie-oozi-W@shell-89de] Error, 
java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at java.util.Hashtable.hash(Hashtable.java:239)
        at java.util.Hashtable.get(Hashtable.java:434)
        at java.util.Properties.getProperty(Properties.java:951)
        at java.util.Properties.getProperty(Properties.java:970)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.get(Configuration.java:1146)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
```

And I googled a result for it :
https://qnalist.com/questions/6182061/shell-action-error
but I can't change the value of nameNode;

The generated configurations in job.properties as below :

```
Name    Value
hue-id-w    50001
jobTracker  yarn-rm-ha
mapreduce.job.user.name hdfs
nameNode    dwparallelspace
oozie.use.system.libpath    True
oozie.wf.application.path   hdfs://dwparallelspace/user/hue/oozie/deployments/_hdfs_-oozie-50001-1461739750.76
user.name   hdfs
```

Anyone can help ? Very appreciated for help!

BTW, if I use oozie job to run this job.properties(just add hdfs:// to nameNode ), the workflow works well.

Answer (score 0):

Its the issue with how you name your namenode in properties file. I had the same issue and fixed it